# Where to save program data on win xp Vista and Windows 7

Tags: xml, windows, file, save

I am developing one application and I wish to save xml data files on Windows XP, Windows 7 And Windows Vista Can any one tell which folder I have use so it will work for all these three OS so user can read write to xml files from my program.

Answer (score 3):

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\YourCompanyName\YourProductName
```

Comment: %ALLUSERSPROFILE% points to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users on XP, and not C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

Answer (score -1):

program files, or windows

Comment: program files surely will not allow  write data to a  normal user it need admin rights